# Как использовать type io.ReadCloser в качестве byte массива

Tags: golang

У меня есть обычный код:

```
req, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error")
} else {
    fmt.Println("OK")

    content := []byte(req.Body) // или req.Header 
    fmt.Printf("%s", hex.Dump(content))
}
```

Как мне использовать/конвертировать/преобразовать `req.Byte, req.Header` в `[]byte` массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правило, вам не нужно читать все байты из `Body`, потому что вы можете передать его напрямую, например в `json.NewDecoder`. Иногда чтение может быть вредным, если например передаётся большой файл. Если же вам действительно это нужно, можете использовать [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll):

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%s", b)
```

---

Вывести же хексдамп хедеров можно так:

```
dumper := hex.Dumper(os.Stdout)
err := resp.Header.Write(dumper)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8J9s7tpj3e.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает!

Comment: А что использовать если пишет: cannot use req (type http.Header) as type io.Reader in argument to ioutil.ReadAll: http.Header does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)

Comment: @massive А зачем вы хедеры туда суёте? Почитайте про работу с `net/http` в официальной документации: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/. Дальше сами.

Comment: мне нужно преобразовать мои хедеры в хекс-дамп и отобразить это. Мне не нужна какая-либо работа с http, мне просто нужно преобразить и вывести дамп на экран.

Comment: @massive Нужна, потому что вы основ не понимаете. Зачем вы вообще пытаетесь читать тело запроса, если вам только заголовки нужны? Простого `log.Println(resp.Header)` хватило бы.

Comment: вы понимаете что я вам написал? Меня не интересуют другие способа вывода информации типа log.Println. Мне нужен корректный вывод hex-dump. И про тело я написал ради примера.

Comment: @massive См. правку.

Comment: Спасибо большое.